# Cannot add any new .H file to target when adding it to project,

Tags: iphone, xcode, file, target

i dont know what to do. I cannot add any .H file to Target in my projects. I tried add it from Add FIle, from drag and drop then info file and check target. Its greyed. when i try to add new file and choose H a cannot check to add it to target. whats is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers are not compiled, so they don't get added to the target.

Look at all the headers currently in your project like your XxxxxAppDelegate.h, you'll see it's not added to the target either.

Answer (score 1):

the header files are not compiled into the project, only the source files and frameworks.  The header files are only there to tell the compiler what it can expect in regards to sending messages to objects

Comment: ok, but when i made mainview.h file and want to import it in appviewcontroller like "#import mainview.h" it shows me that cannot find file or directory

Comment: ok, now its ok but: i made some avPlayer1 in MainView.h, then import mainview.h in viewcontroller but it shows me that avplayer1 is undeclared :(